# How to manipulate loaded data from CSV file with D3js

Tags: d3.js

Hello So I am loading a CSV file as follow

```
d3.csv("filename.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.percentage = d["market share"];
        });
```

the file looks something like this

```
"Things","market share"
"thing1",50
"thing2",30
"thing3",10
"thing4",3.5
"thing5",2.7
"thing6",2.5
"thing7",0.6
"thing8",0.4
"Others",0.3
```

and I am creating the rectangles like this

```
.attr("width", function(d) { return d.percentage * 10})
```

If I do this the result will be 9 rectangles(one for each percentage in the file)

What I'd like to do is add all the values that are lower than 5 to "Others" and then create the rectangles. so the result would be 4 rectangles. With "thing1" being 50, "thing2" being 30, "thing3" being 10 and "Others" being 10.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'd say that you probably want to create the file you're loading like this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a json list and having something that works would be a good first step. Then you can load the csv file as a second step.